# Securing a REST service in an embedded machine on a private network

Tags: oauth-2.0, cryptography

I am trying to secure a set of embedded devices that I am working with that do not have access to the Internet (they are on the private side of a dual NIC pc that does not route one to the other). Here is a summary of the problem:

Suppose I have two network-connected light bulbs (bulb A and bulb B) each controlled by an internal embedded computer (e.g. Rasberry PI) running linux. Each controller exposes a REST method accessible from the LAN to toggle it from on to off and vice versa.

The two light bulbs are connected to a private network (e.g. 192.168.0.x). Also on this same private network is a PC with two NICSs running a web browser - one NIC connected to the private network and the other connected to the public Internet. The PC has access to both the private network and the public Internet but does not route any traffic from one NIC to the other NIC, keeping the private network completely isolated from the public network.

On the internet, there is an authenticating server called lightbulb.com that keeps track of registered users that are allowed to toggle one (or possibly both) of the light bulbs. Bob and Alice have previously registered with lightbulb.com and Bob was given permission to control light bulb B and Alice was given permission to control light bulb A.

When Bob is logged into lightbulb.com on the PC, Ajax calls from the web browser to the REST interface on light bulb B should be acted upon by light bulb B (i.e. turn the light on or off). However, when Bob is
logged into lightbulb.com, Ajax calls from the web browser to the REST interface on light bulb A should be rejected because lightbulb.com has not given Bob permission to control light bulb A. Alice's situation is the opposite of Bob's.

Since the light bulbs are on the private network and have no access to the Internet, how can they determine whether or not to act upon or reject a REST method request, given (a) authentication and authorization of Bob/Alice are done at lightbulb.com, not on the PC; and (b) the light bulbs cannot directly access lightbulb.com to validate credentials.

I am thinking that Oauth2 might help here?

Comment: Use Public/Private keys and digital signatures. Lightbulb.com creates a packet, usually JSON with approved details (who can do what) and signs the packet with the private key. Light bulb A verifies the packet with the public key. A reads the packet and now knows who is verified to do what. Very simple problem. There are lots of Q/A on Stackoverflow for this type of problem.

Comment: Thanks John, my friend suggested Oauth2 for this, but it doesn't seem like Oauth2 is used for this purpose. I think you are right, public/private keys seems more appropriate. Is it even possible using Oauth2 ?

Comment: Yes, but for your use case difficult to implement. OAuth is not the right solution for you. Digital signatures are simple and fast to implement.

Comment: I agree, digital signatures are the way to go. But my friend insists that Oauth2 could work too but I disagree. It seems to me that Oauth2 is a technology for using a third party authority to authenticate a user, but this does not help in authenticating a REST request to a device that is not on the Internet. My opinion is that there is no way to use Oauth2 to solve Alice and Bob's problem.

Comment: Just because something can work (OAuth) does not mean that you should. OAuth in your case is over-complicated. You need to generate Access and Refresh Tokens, manage token expiration, refresh, etc. Digital signatures are easy. Use the correct tool/technology for the problem at hand. Use the wrong tool/technology and spend ALL your time trying to make it work and handle all the corner cases. As I like to say, I can play 9 holes of golf with only my putter, but I think I will use my drivers at the tee.